# Gamma function proof of gamma $\;Γ(1/2) = \sqrt \pi\;$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, factorial, gamma-function

So our teacher doesnt use the same demonstration as most other sites use for proving that gamma of a half is the square root of pi.
I dont understand the demonstration from the first step because he uses the Wallis product but first he represents $Γ(1/2)$ as :

$$Γ(n + 1/2) = 2^{-n}Γ(1/2)\prod_{k=1..n}(2k-1)$$

This is just the first step and i dont undderstand how they get that..
I understand the gamme function and that when you integrate it you get $Γ(x+1) = xΓ(x)$ and i know i need to somehow use this identity but i dunno how.

Comment: $$\Gamma(1+\tfrac{1}{2}) = \tfrac{1}{2}\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}) = 2^{-1}(2\cdot 1-1)\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2});\; \Gamma(2+\tfrac{1}{2}) = (1+\tfrac{1}{2})\Gamma(1+\tfrac{1}{2}) = 2^{-1}(2\cdot 2 - 1)\Gamma(1+\tfrac{1}{2}) = 2^{-2}(2\cdot 2-1)(2\cdot 1-1)\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2})$$ And so on.

Comment: A pity the above is just a comment and not an answer, as it is the clearest one, imo, to the OP's post.

Comment: @Timbuc The OP was looking for ideas as to why and how the lecturer used the associated formula on line 4, Daniel's comment is fine as a comment, but doesn't explore how it potentially arose.

Comment: @user135688 could you please say why don't you accept any of the solutions below? This could help the authors below to refine their derivations or that you get a yet more tailored answer ...

Comment: @Autolatry "how it potentially arose"? Anyway, I think it definitely does as he's using exactly what the OP mentiones at the end of its question: $\;\Gamma(1+x)=x\Gamma (x)\;$ . This, together with an easy inductive argument on the above is all that's needed.

Comment: To get a decimal, you can expand as a series and use many more terms than the upper bound to get [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%282+%28-33%29%5Ek%29%2F%28%28-1+%2B+2+k%29+sqrt%2833%29+k%21%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D). Also, same sprite on editor and Op

Answer (score 19):

Here why $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$
  :$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\intop_{t=0}^{+\infty}t^{\frac{1}{2}-1}e^{-t}dt=\intop_{t=0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt,$$
 and with $y=\sqrt{t}$, $dy=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}}$, we get$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\intop_{y=0}^{+\infty}e^{-y^{2}}dy=\intop_{y=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^{2}}dy=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

Comment: The OP knew this result, but wanted clarification on his/her lecturer's demonstration.

Comment: I was not sure of this because of the title... but it can still be usefull for anyone who wants to see the calculus.

Comment: Absolutely! Your post is perfectly correct.

Comment: For some reason, I was not able to think of this despite of having the formula XD. Thanks so much @Nicolas!

Answer (score 5):

From the Legendre duplication formula;
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(z) \; \Gamma\left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right) = 2^{1-2z} \; \sqrt{\pi} \; \Gamma(2z). 
\end{equation}
We can re-arrange by dividing by $\Gamma(z)$ and considering the quotient
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\Gamma(2n)}{\Gamma(n)} &=& \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \left(2n(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4)(2n-5)\ldots\right)\\
                             &=& \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \left(2^{n+1}n(2n-1)(n-1)(2n-3)(n-2)(2n-5)(n-3)\ldots\right)\\
                             &=& \frac{1}{\Gamma(n)} \left(2^{n+1}n! \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2n-(2k+1))\right)\\
                             &=& 2^{n+1} \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2n-(2k+1))
\end{eqnarray}
Which means that
\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma\left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right)&=& 2^{1-2n} \sqrt{\pi} 2^{n+1} \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2n-(2k+1)) \\
                                  &=& \sqrt{\pi} 2^{-n} \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2n-(2k+1))
\end{eqnarray}
In general for non-integer $n$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right) &=& {(2n)! \over 4^n n!} \sqrt{\pi} \\
                                 &=& \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n} \sqrt{\pi} \\
                                 &=& \sqrt{\pi} \left[ {n-\frac{1}{2}\choose n} n! \right]
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I found three mistakes in this derivation. 2nd equation: Γ(2n)≠(2n)!
but instead, Γ(2n)=(2n−1)!. Obviously the same for Γ(n). Also, one gets $2^{n−1}$ instead of $2^{n+1}$. Finally, the product in the third equation should be $...(2n-(2k-1))$. If you agree, edit your answer please

Answer (score 5):

Through $\Gamma(x+1)=x\,\Gamma(x)$ we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) &=& \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right) = \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{3}\right)\\&=&\ldots\;=\color{red}{\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 3):

We use [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#properties) $\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)=  \frac\pi{\sin(\pi z)}$ with $z=\frac12$.
We then have $\Gamma(1/2)^2=\frac\pi{\sin( \frac\pi2)}$.
Since $\sin( \frac\pi2)=1$ we now have $\Gamma(1/2)^2=\pi$. Finally therefore $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$. Not $-\sqrt\pi$ because we know $\Gamma( 1/2) > 0$.

Comment: Why is it true that $\Gamma( 1/2) > 0$?